# Tomcat Cluster configuration issue: two nodes do not synchronize with each other

Tags: java, tomcat, virtual-machine, cluster-computing

I want to set up a simple Tomcat cluster of two nodes.
I have two VMs which are members of the same local network and can see each other.

In both Tomcats cluster config section (in server.xml) is similar:

```
    <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" channelSendOptions="8">
        <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager" expireSessionsOnShutdown="false" notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
        <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
          <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService" address="228.0.0.4" port="41166" frequency="500" dropTime="3000"/>
          <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver" address="auto" port="4000" autoBind="100" selectorTimeout="5000" maxThreads="6"/>
          <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
            <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
          </Sender>
          <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
          <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
        </Channel>
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" filter=""/>
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>
        <Valve className="org.jasig.cas.client.tomcat.v7.StaticUriLogoutValve" logoutUri="/j_spring_cas_security_logout"/>
        <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
        <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
    </Cluster>
```

When I start both Tomcats, my application is up and running, but the session is not replicated (I have to log in two times).

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I don't have any load balancer yet. It looks like tomcat cluster use broadcasting and doesn't need any certral node. Please, correct me here if I'm wrong.

Comment: Where is this cluster running? Do you have any confirmation that the two instances see each other?

Comment: chrylis: I'm trying to figure that out, thx for the tip.

Comment: I asked about the setup because some VM environments (notably Amazon EC2) have limited support for broadcast/multicast, and just because you can make an explicit connection doesn't mean a discovery mechanism will work.

Answer (score -1):

Tomcat document sites that you indeed need a load balancer configured for sticky sessions. Please check the last bullet point: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html#Cluster_Basics

Looks like broadcasting is not actually broadcasting sessions across nodes in a cluster.

Comment: I don't really understand the point of that last item. Why would we ever need session sharing if we used sticky sessions?